# how to create multiple json arrays and pass all arrays in the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to Json and stuck at a simple syntax which am not able to figure out

i have a json:

```
{"Full_Talktime":[
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"}, 
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"}
]}
```

and my function:

```
$(function() {
   $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data.Full_Talktime, function(index, plan) {


            var  tblPara = $('<p class="col1">').html("<b>Talktime</b><br>");
            var  tblValidity = $('<p class="col2">').html("<b>Validity</b><br>");
            var  tblPrice = $('<p class="col3">');
            var  tblDescription = $('<p class="row2">').html("<b>Description</b><br>");
            var  endline =$('<div class="end">');
            tblPara.append('<div class="para">' + plan.Talktime + '</div>');
            tblValidity.append('<div class="para">' + plan.Validity + '</div>');
            tblPrice.append('<div class="col3para">' + plan.Price + '</div>');
            tblDescription.append('<div class="para">' + plan.Description + '</div>');
        console.log(plan);

           $(".content").append(tblPara).append(tblValidity).append(tblPrice).append(tblDescription).append(endline);
     });
   });
});
```

i need to create a similar json like this:

```
{"Special_Recharge":[
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"}, 
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"}
]}
```

and run the same function for it.I need help with Json syntax and running the same function for both of the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two json headers "Full_Talktime" and "Special_Recharge", so there must be something that will identify which data(header) its going to be , may be u r using two separate ajax calls to get that.

So depending on that condition first read json data data.Special_Recharge / data.Full_Talktime,
Eg var dataFromDB = data.Special_Recharge & var dataFromDB = data.Full_TalkTime

And then call ur function loop :

$.each(dataFromDB, function(index, plan) { ...

Comment: Thankyou,also need help to include both json arrays in a single file and then run the same function for each array.

Comment: I think u need to merge both json arrays under one parent json array so that u can pass the parent json array to ur function.

Comment: I think u need to merge both json arrays under one parent json array so that u can pass the parent json array to ur function.
I mean data.parentArray.Special_Recharge and data.parentArray.FulltalkTime array